# How to use Rollup Grouping Function error in SQL DW?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse

I'm getting the error thatROLLUP is not a function name but the documentation says it should work
 Msg 104162, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
'ROLLUP' is not a recognized built-in function name.

I've tried group by grouping sets but it told me the syntax was wrong, that's when I saw that grouping sets doesn't work with DW

```
SELECT S.[ProjectID]
      ,P.ProjectId
      ,P.Level2
      ,S.[PTDIncurredAmount]
      ,S.[PriorYearIncurredAmount]
      ,S.[YTDIncurredAmount], sum([YTDIncurredAmount]) as CTDActuals
  FROM [Fact].[vProjectSummary] as S
  JOIN dim.vProject as P on S.ProjectID=P.ProjectId
  Group by ROLLUP (P.Level2, S.ProjectID )
```

If anyone can point me to more specifically the problem with this code for Azure SQL DW I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-group-by-options.md#what-does-group-by-do) documentation *ROLLUP* is not supported:

> The GROUP BY T-SQL clause aggregates data to a summary set of rows.
>   GROUP BY has some options that SQL Data Warehouse does not support.
>   These options have workarounds.
>
> These options are
>
> GROUP BY with ROLLUP
>
> GROUPING SETS
>
> GROUP BY with CUBE

The workaround suggested is to use `UNION ALL` to simulate the `ROLLUP`.  If I take a simplified version of your query

```
SELECT S.projectID, p.Level2, SUM( [YTDIncurredAmount] )
FROM [Fact].[vProjectSummary] AS S
    INNER JOIN dim.vProject AS P ON S.ProjectID = P.ProjectId
GROUP BY ROLLUP ( P.Level2, S.ProjectID )
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

By using `ROLLUP` this query requests the following aggregations:

- Level2 and ProjectId
- Level2
- Grand total

You can simulate this with `UNION ALL`:

```
-- Level 2 and ProjectID
SELECT S.ProjectID, p.Level2, SUM( [YTDIncurredAmount] )
FROM [Fact].[vProjectSummary] AS S
    INNER JOIN dim.vProject AS P ON S.ProjectID = P.ProjectID
GROUP BY S.ProjectID, p.Level2

UNION ALL

-- Level 2 
SELECT NULL, p.Level2, SUM( [YTDIncurredAmount] )
FROM [Fact].[vProjectSummary] AS S
    INNER JOIN dim.vProject AS P ON S.ProjectID = P.ProjectID
GROUP BY p.Level2

UNION ALL

-- Grand total
SELECT NULL, NULL, SUM( [YTDIncurredAmount] )
FROM [Fact].[vProjectSummary] AS S
    INNER JOIN dim.vProject AS P ON S.ProjectID = P.ProjectID
```

I could not get any queries using `ROLLUP` to work although this link does seem to suggest it's possible:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

There is also a feedback item you can vote for here:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/35836048-grouping-and-group-by-rollup-functions-needs-to-be

Comment: Paging @RonDunn - is there an issue with the docs?  Does seem to imply `ROLLUP`  is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Azure Synapse Analytics (was SQL Data Warehouse) and the ROLLUP option works. The following page shows a separate definition for the 'GROUP BY' clause in Azure Synapse Analytics where ROLLUP is supported but CUBE and GROUPING SETS are not

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

I assume this will change as the product matures.